# MySQL Convert data VARCHAR to DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, varchar

The table `users` was badly designed. 
The `created_at` and `updated_at` records were set with the VARCHAR type and the values were placed in them for a long time in the format like `20.10.2017 8:10`.

It is necessary to convert fields to the `DATETIME` type in MySQL, saving the values entered earlier.

The `STR_TO_DATETIME` function is not suitable because it changes the output format, but not the `VARCHAR` data type itself to `DATETIME` data type in the table.

```
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY created_at DATETIME
```

does not work

Error message:

> SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '06.01.2020 8:10' for column 'created_at' at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You date has the false Format convert it to the correct mysql time and then alter the table

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.19    |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users
>     (`created_at` varchar(20))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO users
>     (`created_at`)
> VALUES
>     ("06.01.2020 8:10"),
>     ("07.01.2020 8:10"),
>     ("08.01.2020 8:10"),
>     ("09.01.2020 8:10")
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT STR_TO_DATE(created_at, "%d.%m.%Y %k:%i") FROM users;
> ```
>
> ```
> | STR_TO_DATE(created_at, "%d.%m.%Y %k:%i") |
> | :---------------------------------------- |
> | 2020-01-06 08:10:00                       |
> | 2020-01-07 08:10:00                       |
> | 2020-01-08 08:10:00                       |
> | 2020-01-09 08:10:00                       |
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE users SET created_at = STR_TO_DATE(created_at, "%d.%m.%Y %k:%i");
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM users;
> ```
>
> ```
> | created_at          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-01-06 08:10:00 |
> | 2020-01-07 08:10:00 |
> | 2020-01-08 08:10:00 |
> | 2020-01-09 08:10:00 |
> ```

> ```
> ALTER TABLE users MODIFY created_at DATETIME
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM users;
> ```
>
> ```
> | created_at          |
> | :------------------ |
> | 2020-01-06 08:10:00 |
> | 2020-01-07 08:10:00 |
> | 2020-01-08 08:10:00 |
> | 2020-01-09 08:10:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=86ea17b14a5969f0b6a3d5f705f86c93)*

Answer (score 2):

When you change a column from `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`, there's no way for you to specify custom parsing of the string, it has to be in MySQL's default format.

So you'll need to do this in multiple steps:

1. Add a DATETIME column.
2. Fill in the new column by parsing the VARCHAR column with `STR_TO_DATE()`
3. Remove the old column and rename the new column.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD created_at_dt DATETIME, updated_at_dt DATETIME;
UPDATE users
SET created_at_dt = STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i'),
    updated_at_dt = STR_TO_DATE(updated_at, '%d.%m.%Y %h:%i');
ALTER TABLE users 
    DROP created_at, DROP updated_at, 
    RENAME COLUMN created_at_dt TO created_at, RENAME COLUMN updated_at_dt TO updated_at;
```

Comment: I suggest making sure that the new columns contain valid dates before dropping the original columns. If the STR_TO_DATE() doesn't succeed, it will just store NULLs.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but the task is not to delete or add new columns, but to change the type of existing ones.

Comment: You can't change the type in one step and keep the values.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to work around this is to create new `created_at` and `updated_at` `DATETIME` columns, assign them the parsed date values, and then drop the old columns and rename the new ones. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD new_created_at DATETIME
UPDATE users SET new_created_at = STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%d.%m.%Y %l:%i')
ALTER TABLE users DROP created_at, CHANGE new_created_at created_at DATETIME
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cb2eff775d5b8162987a8d22a17e9831)

As @BillKarwin points out, you should check that `new_created_at` contains valid values *before* dropping the `created_at` column just in case some dates do not match the format. You can check for those cases using

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE new_created_at IS NULL
```

And as @Barmar points out, it is preferable to try this first in a backup copy of the table.

Comment: I suggest making sure that the new columns contain valid dates before dropping the original columns. If the STR_TO_DATE() doesn't succeed, it will just store NULLs.

Comment: @BillKarwin good point. I've updated the answer to mention that.

Comment: And it hardly needs to be mentioned that you should try this first in a backup copy.

Comment: @Barmar indeed. That *should* be obvious, but I've added a note anyway.